# How to fix default marker-icon.png not found in vue 2 leaflet app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, leaflet

I have a simple, sample project at https://github.com/ericg-vue-questions/leaflet-test/tree/feature/simple-marker

(note the feature/simple-marker branch)

The relevant code is in the [LeafletTest.vue](https://github.com/ericg-vue-questions/leaflet-test/blob/feature/simple-marker/src/components/LeafletTest.vue) file

```
<template>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="mapContainer"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import L from 'leaflet';
import Vue from 'vue';

export default {
    name: 'Map',

    methods: {
        async setupLeafletMap() {
            const center = [37, -122];

            const mapDiv = L.map('mapContainer').setView(center, 13);

            var tiles = new L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
                minZoom: 3,
                maxZoom: 8
            }).addTo(mapDiv);

            L.marker(center).addTo(mapDiv);
        }
    },

    async mounted() {
        await Vue.nextTick();
        await this.setupLeafletMap();
    }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
#mapContainer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
</style>
```

When the code run, the default marker shows up as:

[image: broken marker]

The URL in the img tag that `L.marker(center).addTo(mapDiv);` adds to the map is

```
<img src="marker-icon.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive" alt="Marker" tabindex="0" role="button" style="margin-left: -12px; margin-top: -41px; width: 25px; height: 41px; transform: translate3d(250px, 250px, 0px); z-index: 250;">
```

I figure there is something extra I need to do in configuring the vue app so it and leaflet can work together in this case.

What do I need to change so the default marker-icon.png will show up by default?

Comment: What's the url of your IMG tag on map?

Comment: @BigLiao updated question with that information.

Comment: [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/337253) might help.

Comment: @tao Thank you, but I am not sure how. I believe this is a vue configuration issue that I am not sure how to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One answer I found was to modify the `mounted()` method to be:

```
    async mounted() {
        delete L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;

        L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
            iconRetinaUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png'),
            iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'),
            shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png')
        });

        await Vue.nextTick();
        await this.setupLeafletMap();
    }
```

The part that was added was:

```
        delete L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;

        L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
            iconRetinaUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png'),
            iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'),
            shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png')
        });
```

If I understand correctly what is going on here is that webpack will see the require's and assist in making sure the right thing happens. If anyone has a more detailed explanation of why this works, I would be interested.